# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference'?

Tags: java, android

This keeps preventing the app from working on the emulator, but there is nothing on my main activity java file that can be returned as null(I made no changes to it yet)? Where else could there be an error? So far I have just made the layout which includes the normal edit/plain texts, image views, buttons(non-functional for now) and spinners.

java:

```
package com.example.create_recipe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }






}
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTxtRecipeName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/recipe_name"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addThumbnail" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCountry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arya_bold"
            android:text="@string/cuisine"
            android:textColor="#FF6700"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTxtRecipeName" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnCountries"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:entries="@array/countries"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtCountry"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtCountry"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtCountry"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEquipment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arya_bold"
            android:text="@string/equipment"
            android:textColor="#FF6700"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtDuration"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDuration" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtIngredients"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arya_bold"
            android:text="@string/ingredients"
            android:textColor="#FF6700"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTxtEquipment" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMethod"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arya_bold"
            android:text="@string/method"
            android:textColor="#FF6700"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTxtIngredients" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="149dp"
            android:layout_height="149dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addThumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#004E98"
            android:text="@string/thumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/viewThumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/viewThumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewThumbnail" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#004E98"
            android:text="@string/video"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/addThumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/viewVideo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/viewVideo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addThumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/viewVideo"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="149dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPersonalStory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arya_bold"
            android:text="@string/personal_story"
            android:textColor="#FF6700"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTxtMethod" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreateRecipe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#004E98"
            android:text="@string/create_recipe"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editPersonalStory" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPersonalStory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="@string/tell_us_about_your_culture_country"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPersonalStory" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDuration"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arya_bold"
            android:text="@string/approx_cooking_time"
            android:textColor="#FF6700"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtCountry"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtCountry" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnHours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:entries="@array/hours"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtDuration"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtDuration"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtDuration"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtHours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/hrs"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spnHours"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spnHours"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spnHours" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnMinutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:entries="@array/minutes"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spnHours"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtHours"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spnHours"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMinutes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/mins"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spnMinutes"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spnMinutes"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/spnMinutes" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="395dp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTxtEquipment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="@string/_200c_fan_oven"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtEquipment"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTxtIngredients"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="@string/_500g_chicken_diced"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtIngredients"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTxtMethod"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="Pan fry chicken for 10 mins "
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtMethod"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtMethod" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here's the stack-trace:

```
2022-03-29 05:21:41.732 9424-9424/com.example.create_recipe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.create_recipe, PID: 9424
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:454)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
        at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:869)
        at android.widget.Spinner.onMeasure(Spinner.java:618)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onMeasure(AppCompatSpinner.java:438)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$Measurer.measure(ConstraintLayout.java:811)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measure(BasicMeasure.java:466)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.measureChildren(BasicMeasure.java:134)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.analyzer.BasicMeasure.solverMeasure(BasicMeasure.java:278)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.core.widgets.ConstraintWidgetContainer.measure(ConstraintWidgetContainer.java:120)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.resolveSystem(ConstraintLayout.java:1594)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1708)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1441)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:458)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:145)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:496)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6980)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:761)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25833)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3676)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2739)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2179)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1037)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:780)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
2022-03-29 05:21:42.345 9424-9435/com.example.create_recipe W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: @Sup19 , I've just uploaded the track-trace there now

Comment: upload some code that crashes your app

Comment: Did you set an `android:entries` attribute on one of those `<Spinner>`s? Looks like it might be an issue with that. In any case, it'd help to see the layout, along with the code that you had here originally, just so everybody's on the same page.

Comment: @MikeM. All the spinners have the attribute, I've also uploaded the xml and java

Comment: Yeah, looks like something's wrong with at least one of the arrays; a null or empty item, possibly.

Comment: @bbb test with comment both spinners and run.

Comment: Sounds like you're using plain `<array>`s. You must use `<string-array>`s for those.